# What causes the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

This is a question in the book "Cracking the Coding Interview". Here is Java code, but why does it cause the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? I just copied from the book.

```
class Q1_3{ 
    public static void removeDuplicates(char[] str){
        if(str==null) return;
        int len=str.length;
        if(len<2) return;

        int t=1;

        for(int i=1;i<len;++i){
            int j;
            for(j=0;j<t;++j){
                if(str[i]==str[j]) 
                    break;
            }
            if(j==t){
                str[t]=str[i];
                ++t;
            }
        }
        str[t]=0;   //why ?
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        char ss1[] = {'a','b','c','d'};
        char ss2[] = {'a','a','a','a'};
        char ss3[] = {};
        char ss4[] = {'a','a','b','b'};
        removeDuplicates(ss1);
        removeDuplicates(ss2);
        removeDuplicates(ss3);
        removeDuplicates(ss4);
        System.out.println(ss1);
        System.out.println(ss2);
        System.out.println(ss3);
        System.out.println(ss4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `t >= str.length` in some point. Debug your code to know why.

Comment: Best you post the error log as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really weird code, the naming and the use of control structures its... questionable...

The code breaks when there is no duplicated chars, t increases his value in all iterations and at the end is 4, this is what causes de exception.

in the example the code only crash with ss1, and "works" with the others.

Comment: I know the reason about the bug now. But I don't know how to solve the question about "remove the duplicate characters in a string without using any additional buffer" in java, can you help me? or correct the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the code closely, you will find that after comparing the value for the last element in the inner `for` loop you increment the value of `t`, thus the value of `t` will be `str.length`. But, array index start from `0` till `str.length-1`. So eventually, when you try to insert value at index `str.length` you will get the exception.